# There is a bug in Kendo NumericTextBox which exists in function caret(element, position)

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, numeric-textbox

This bug is visible at http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html.

in Grid / Batch editing when you enter a decimal value in column Units in Stock, then click "Save changes"
page does not save the value and the page does not do any saving.

perhaps there is a bug in Kendo NumericTextBox which exists in function caret(element, position)
We get an unspecified error for this bug in our project

Comment: the demo works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is kendo using html5 for those fields?  Looks like a numeric box, which could be a browser-dependent problem.   Works using Chrome Canary for me.  For numeric types to accept decimal, the standard is to specify "step" for the spinner control which defaults to 1.  Try adding a step attribute and setting it to "any" which will still increment by integers but will accept decimals.

```
 UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true, step: "any"} }
```

Or in **[kendo, maybe something like](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/numerictextbox)**

```
 <input id="numerictextbox" />
<script>
 $("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({
  step: "any"
  });
 </script>
```